# Using Gaussian Process For Predicting with Confidence

Tags: regression, machine-learning, normal-distribution, predictive-models, gaussian-process

I have a dataset of [(cluster of points, real location point)], which contains clusters of points (x,y) and for each cluster a real location point.

**My goal is** given a cluster of points, **predict** where is the real location point - what are the (x,y) of the real location point.

In addition I want to predict with 50% confidence that I'm right - so in that case the predicted "real location point" will not be a point but a circle with certainty of 50%.
[image: The Task]

How can I use Gaussian Process in order to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it about your data that suggests you need a Gaussian process to model them?

Comment: @whuber 1) I assume (and it's right) that the points are gaussian distributed, 2) I need the Gaussian Process to give me the certainty

Comment: That doesn't need a Gaussian Process model at all: this is a standard ordinary least squares model to which you can apply the standard formulas for the estimate and its confidence region.

Comment: @whuber Can you elaborate on the confidence region? How can I achieve it with a standard least squares model?

Comment: It depends on a detail: do you suppose the coordinates of the points are independent or could they be correlated?